# Integral of the product of a power function and an arbitrary exponentiated function

Tags: integration, exponentiation

I was only able to find integral tables that solve

$$f(t)=\int t^c e^{kt}dt$$

but the integral I'm trying to solve has a function, not a constant, for the exponent:

$$f(t)=\int t^c e^{g(t)}dt$$

Is there a general analytic solution to this form?

---

The actual integral I'm trying to solve is

$$f(t)=\int t^{a-1} e^{\frac{\ln2}{\lambda}t-\frac{1}{b}t^a}dt$$

where $a$, $b$, and $\lambda$ are all constants.

Comment: not sure it helps but substituting $u = t^a$ yields $$\frac{1}{a} \int \exp\left( \frac{u^{1/a} \ln 2}{\lambda} - \frac{u}{b}\right) du$$

Comment: That's neat. I think there's a missing $1/a$ however—ah, never mind. You fixed it :-)

Comment: Any function can be represented as t^e*^(g(t)), so there is definitely not a general solution, since not all functions can be integrated analytically. For the specific solution, I may be able to help. Let me think.

Comment: I doubt that there's anything you can do with this.